# Given statements $A$ and $B$, are the formulae $(\lnot A) \land (\lnot B)$ and $(\lnot A) \lor (\lnot B)$ equivalent?

Tags: logic, knowledge-representation

If I have 2 statements, say $A$ and $B$, from which I formed 2 formulae:

1. $f_1: (\lnot A) \land (\lnot B)$
2. $f_2: (\lnot A) \lor (\lnot B)$

Are $f_1$ and $f_2$ equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f_1 \vdash f_2$, if and only if $f_2$ must be true if we assume $f_1$ to be true.

Similarly, $f_2 \vdash  f_1$, if and only if $f_1$ must be true if we assume $f_2$ to be true.

Logically, by taking any value for $A$ or $B$, from the domain $\{1, 0 \}$, one could verify that $f_1 \vdash f_2$, because $f_2$ is true whenever $f_1$ is true (for example, when both $A = 0$ and $B = 0$).

However, $f_2 \vdash  f_1$ is not true. As, in two cases, $f_2$ is true (e.g. $A = 0$ and $B=1$, or vice-versa), but $f_1$ is not true.

Comment: This is an old question and answer, but when you use $\vdash$, didn't you want to use $\rightarrow$?

Answer (score 3):

One way of verifying whether two boolean expressions are equivalent is to assign all possibilities to all variables, and comparing all results.

| A | B | f1 | f2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T | T | F | F |
| T | F | F | T |
| F | T | F | T |
| F | F | T | T |

We can see `(F, F, F, T)` does not equal `(F, T, T, T)`, for example for the assignment `(A, B) = (T, F)` we get result `(f1, f2) = (F, T)` , meaning `f1` $\ne$ `f2`.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easy to get a quick intuition of the truth value of logical statements involving negations by converting them wherever possible.

So assume by way of contradiction that $\textit{f}_1 \iff \textit{f}_2$, then the two-way contrapositive $\neg \textit{f}_1 \iff \neg \textit{f}_2$ also holds, hence $A \lor B \iff A \land B$ (De Morgan's law). Since $A \lor B \implies A \land B$ is easily confirmed false (by plugging in A=True and B=False) this is a contradiction. $\Box$